# How can I test two strings for equivalence in JavaScript, considering null and empty string the same?

Tags: javascript

If I compare "a" and "b", that should be false.
If I compare "a" and "a", that should be true.
If I compare "" and null, that should be true.

I could write my own method, but thought there was perhaps a JavaScript shortcut.

Edit: I was thinking something like this:

```
areDbSame(s1, s2) {
    if (s1 === null) s1 = "";
    if (s2 === null) s2 = "";
    return s1 === s2;
}
```

Edit2: Settled on this version:

```
areDbSame(s1, s2) {
    return (s1 === null ? "" : s1) === (s2 === null ? "" : s2);
}
```

Comment: You are most likely going to have to write your own.

Comment: You need a custom method because "" and null will never be the same. To evaluate that case to true, you need custom logic.

Comment: Because someone thought it deserved to be -1. Questions that normally ask for a shortcut without a demo normally get downvoted. I am surprised it is not lower yet.

Comment: I added a demonstration

Comment: Yep, that would be the way to go. You need to do the same for `s2` though. Is your question now whether you can do this without writing your own function? The answer to do that would be "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just before you test the equality of your string, you could do a simple one line enforcement, by converting to `''` in the case of `null`. For example (if you also don't care about undefined, false, etc):

```
// testString becomes the one you are testing
var testString = myString || '';
```

If you only want to ensure `null` is blank

```
var testString = (myString === null) ? '' : myString;
```

Then you can simply do your string comparisons using `testString`, and not worry about the null equalities.

---

IMO this is the cleanest answer because it doesn't convolute the original equality testing of javascript strings. It is the same as saying, let's split the problem up into two parts.

- *1)* When should my string be considered blank, and
- *2)* Now I can just check for regular string equality.

Answer (score 1):

```
function areEqualStrings(a, b) {
  var otherEqualValues = ['', null];

  if(typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string') {
    return a === b;
  } else if(otherEqualValues.indexOf(a) > -1 && otherEqualValues.indexOf(b) > -1) {
    return !a === !b;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

When coercing JavaScript values, `!null` is `true` and `!''` is `true`, so those would result in being equal.

Here's the test (screenshotted from my console):

[image]

Comment: You don't need to use two `!!` one is enough

Comment: What about `areEqualString('', 0)`? Do you assume that the input will always be strings and `null`?

Comment: I thought about posting something similar (simpler maybe) as josh, but `''`and `0`was the reason why i doge this question

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it. It type checks first and short circuits otherwise.

```
function stringCompare(a, b) {
    if (((a === null || typeof a === 'string') ||
         (b === null || typeof b === 'string')) &&
        ((a === '' && b === null) ||
         (b === '' && a === null) ||
         (a === b))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it hasn`t. The two first cases you can do naturally using operator =.
The third case it is impossible because "" is considered a empty string and null has any type. So they never can be true naturally. To do this, you have to write your own method.

Just to be clear. You can use operators = (equal) to do comparison:

## ==    equal to

```
`x == 8     false
 x == 5     true
 x == "5"   true
```

## === equal value and equal type

```
 x === 5    true
 x === "5"  false
```

Hope it helps

Comment: *"... and null has any type."* `null` is actually of type Null.